# Styled qr codes in react select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qr-code, react-select

I need to create react-select where every option is different styled qr code with js library: qr-code-styling.

The problem is that in documentation qr code are appended to dom elements, and options in react-select are created dynamically. I can't find a way to append these qr codes to my options. I think the problem is that, I can't properly create refs, which I can use to apped the codes. Is there any way to do it?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, createRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import QRCodeStyling from "qr-code-styling";
import Select from "react-select";

const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
  data: "https://qr-code-styling.com",
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  image:
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Facebook_f_logo_%282019%29.svg",
  dotsOptions: {
    color: "#4267b2",
    type: "rounded"
  },
  imageOptions: {
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    margin: 20
  }
});
const qrCode2 = new QRCodeStyling({
  data: "https://qr-code-styling.com",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  image:
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Facebook_f_logo_%282019%29.svg",
  dotsOptions: {
    color: "red",
    type: "rounded"
  },
  imageOptions: {
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    margin: 20
  }
});

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    qrcode: qrCode
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    qrcode: qrCode2
  }
];

export default function App() {
  let refs = useRef([createRef(), createRef()]);

  const optionLabel = (option, index) => <div ref={refs.current[option.id]} />;

  useEffect(() => {
    refs.current.forEach((ref) => qrCode.append(ref.current));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="select-logo"
        getOptionLabel={optionLabel}
        options={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-code-styling-react-example-forked-hz100?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have the Select let you know *when* to append the QR codes, by using its `onMenuOpen` prop. First, though, we need to be able to find the element to append, so we need to add a `formatOptionLabel` (which is what I suspect you meant to use, instead of `getOptionLabel` in your sandbox):

```
<Select
    formatOptionLabel={({ id }) => <div id={`qr-code-option-${id}`} />}
    ...etc
/>
```

Then, we can add a state variable to be triggered when the menu loads:

```
const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = React.useState(false)
```

and, when the menuIsOpen, append the options to their qrCodes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        let o = document.getElementById('qr-code-option-' + d.id)
        if (o) {
            d.qrcode?.append(o)
        }
    })
}, [menuIsOpen])
```

Finally, we use the `onMenuOpen` and `onMenuClose` props to trigger the state changes, resulting in the desired result! The full code of the App component is now:

```
export default function App() {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = React.useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    data.forEach(d => {
      let o = document.getElementById(`qr-code-option-${d.id}`)
      if (o) {
        d.qrcode?.append(o)
      }
    })
  }, [menuIsOpen])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="select-logo"
        formatOptionLabel={({ id }) => <div id={`qr-code-option-${id}`} />}
        onMenuOpen={() => setMenuIsOpen(true)}
        onMenuClose={() => setMenuIsOpen(false)}
        options={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

which gives:

[image: a Select dropdown with QR Codes inside]